# algorithmic function to create all possible combinations from a list of vectors

Tags: c#, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I have a list of lists of int `<List<List<int>>` which represents a directional vector

for instance

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,4)
(3,5)
(4,3)
(5,1)
```

and I want to create all possible routes with those vectors so that the final route doesn't create an endless circle (ends on itself)

so:

```
(1,2)
(1,3)
(2,4)
(3,5)
(4,3)
(5,1)
(1,2,4)
(1,2,4,3)
(1,2,4,3,5)
(1,2,4,3,5,1)
(1,3,5)
(1,3,5,1)
(2,4,3)
(2,4,3,5)
(2,4,3,5,1)
(2,4,3,5,1,2)
(3,5,1)
etc...
```

I haven't found an efficient method of doing such a thing.

I have previous tried creating all possible combinations using

```
    private IEnumerable<int> constructSetFromBits(int i)
    {
        for (int n = 0; i != 0; i /= 2, n++)
        {
            if ((i & 1) != 0)
                yield return n;
        }
    }

  public IEnumerable<List<T>> ProduceWithRecursion(List<T> allValues) 
    {
        for (var i = 0; i < (1 << allValues.Count); i++)
        {
            yield return ConstructSetFromBits(i).Select(n => allValues[n]).ToList();
        }
    }
```

which worked well but ignored the direction aspect of the problem.

The method doesn't have to be recursive although I suspect that might be the most sensible way to go about it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like breadth first search:

```
private static IEnumerable<List<int>> BreadthFirstSearch(IEnumerable<List<int>> source) {
  List<List<int>> frontier = source
    .Select(item => item.ToList())
    .ToList();

  while (frontier.Any()) {
    for (int i = frontier.Count - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
      List<int> path = frontier[i];

      yield return path;

      frontier.RemoveAt(i);

      // prevent loops
      if (path.IndexOf(path[path.Count - 1]) < path.Count - 1)
        continue;

      int lastVertex = path[path.Count - 1];

      var NextVertexes = source
        .Where(edge => edge[0] == lastVertex)
        .Select(edge => edge[1])
        .Distinct();

      foreach (var nextVertex in NextVertexes) {
        var nextPath = path.ToList();

        nextPath.Add(nextVertex);

        frontier.Add(nextPath);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Test

```
List<List<int>> list = new List<List<int>>() {
  new List<int>() {1, 2},
  new List<int>() {1, 3},
  new List<int>() {2, 4},
  new List<int>() {3, 5},
  new List<int>() {4, 3},
  new List<int>() {5, 1},
};

var result = BreadthFirstSearch(list)
  .Select(way => string.Format("({0})", string.Join(",", way)));

Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result));
```

Result:

```
(5,1)
(4,3)
(3,5)
(2,4)
(1,3)
(1,2)
(1,2,4)
(1,3,5)
(2,4,3)
(3,5,1)
(4,3,5)
(5,1,3)
(5,1,2)
(5,1,2,4)
(5,1,3,5)
(4,3,5,1)
(3,5,1,3)
(3,5,1,2)
(2,4,3,5)
(1,3,5,1)
(1,2,4,3)
(1,2,4,3,5)
(2,4,3,5,1)
(3,5,1,2,4)
(4,3,5,1,3)
(4,3,5,1,2)
(5,1,2,4,3)
(5,1,2,4,3,5)
(4,3,5,1,2,4)
(3,5,1,2,4,3)
(2,4,3,5,1,3)
(2,4,3,5,1,2)
(1,2,4,3,5,1)
```

Comment: Thanks for that! Looks better than what I had going on... 
I'll try it and I'll resolve accordingly